# List Slicing in Python 2

Tags: python

I am working on the hangman lessons in Invent with Python. For hours I am trying to understand the 2nd and 3rd line in the for loop below.

```
for i in range(len(secretWord)):
    if secretWord[i] in correctLetters:
        blanks = blanks[:i] + secretWord[i] + blanks[i+1:]
```

I am aware it is list slicing, but while I do know what list slicing is, I don't get why the + operator is used.

Appreciate anyone explaining this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is to concatenate the strings.

```
  blanks = blanks[:i] + secretWord[i] + blanks[i+1:]
```

It will concatenate the `blank` string till i, character at i of `secretWord` and the `blank` string from i + 1 till the end.

**Example:**

```
blanks = "Welcome"
secretWord = "WELCOME"
i = 3
print blanks[:i] + secretWord[i] + blanks[i+1:]
```

Will print

```
WelCome
```

So basically the above seen line replaces character at `i` of `blank` with the character at `i` of `secretWord`.

Comment: Simply awesome explanation!

Answer (score 2):

The `+` is used as it would normally be used for - addition.

`for i in range(len(secretWord)):` loops through `[0, 1, ... len(secretWord)]` assigning `i` to each item every loop.

So in the first loop, `blanks = blanks[:i] + secretWord[i] + blanks[i+1:]` is :

```
blanks = blanks[:0] + secretWord[0] + blanks[0+1:]
```

Aka:

```
blanks = blanks[:0] + secretWord[0] + blanks[1:]
#                                            ^ 0 + 1 == 1
```

If you mean the `+` in between each slice, that is used for *string concatenation*:

```
>>> print 'hello ' + 'world'
hello world
```

Answer (score 1):

When used with strings, the `+` operator in Python concatenates the strings.